# Laravel with Vue Instance in a subdirectory not working

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am currently building a Laravel app with two dashboards for the admin and the second one for the users. The user backend should run under the domain `/user-dashboard/`. The admin backend under `/dashboard`.

In Vue I use Vue route and I have a problem with my baseurl. Because Vue router does not add the Vue routes links to my baseurl. It always starts from '/'. How can I fix it?

Here are my **web.php** and **router.js** and **vite.config.js**

**web.php**

```php
Route::get('/user-dashboard', function () {
    return view('userdashboard');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('user.dashboard');

Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');
```

**routes/index.js**

```js
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/HomeView.vue";
import Profile from '../views/ProfileView.vue';
import NotFound from '../views/NotFoundView.vue';

const routes = [
    {
        path: "/",
        name: "Home",
        component: Home,
    },
    {
        path: "/profile",
        name: "Profile",
        component: Profile,
    },
    {
        path: "/:catchAll(.*)",
        component: NotFound,
    },  
];


const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    base: '/user-dashboard/',
    routes,
});

export default router;
```

**vite.config.js**

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue"

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the base path in your routes/index.js file in the createWebHistory function. Change your file as follows:

```js
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory( '/user-dashboard/'),
    routes,
});
```

It would be more elegant in terms of customisability if you add the constant e.g.: `VITE_BASE_VUE_PATH="/user-dashboard"` to your **.env** file and then pass `import.meta.env.VITE_VUE_PATH`. Like:

```js
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory( import.meta.env.VITE_VUE_PATH ),
    routes,
});
```

Then you have to adapt the Laravel router so that you can intercept all requests that run via /user-dashboard.

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'user-dashboard'], function() {
  Route::get('/', function () {
      return view('userdashboard');
  });

  Route::get('{any}', function () {
      return view('userdashboard');
  });
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('user.dashboard');
```

That should work!